# Layout website IE8 and lower looks wrong CSS3

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

My website PackageNow.net is based on HTML5 and CSS3. All other browsers do not give any problems but IE8 and lower do.

[Website wrong view](http://royvs.synology.me/photo/#Albums/album_57656273697465/photo_57656273697465_696d6167652e706e67)

I tried to apply the PIE solution, and tried to apply different CSS styles attached to the website if IE is lower then 9

The website should look like this...

[Website correct view](http://royvs.synology.me/photo/#Albums/album_57656273697465/photo_57656273697465_696d616765202831292e706e67)

I would understand if the layout would be a little but different, but this is not normal...

Please help because some of my customers still have IE8 and below. I added a script that says that there browser is out of date, but I need to provide a website that works. otherwise i lose customers.

Sorry for my bad english, hope you understand what i try to say.

Thanks! Roy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that's probably the expected behaviour (depending on what you're doing) and is perfectly normal for IE8.

in IE8 a lot of HTML5 mark-up / elements won't be understood batively by the browser and it won't know if it's supposed to display in-line or as block and you need to provide the [HTML5 shim](https://code.google.com/p/html5shim/) to deal with those.

Also there are very few supported CSS selector rules in IE8 and a list can be found at [Selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/) how getting support for thise. Of course you'll then need something like JQuery to provide that support

Also some of the :pseudo attributes just aren't supported and you need to write JavaScript to emulate these and add appropriate style rules too..

There are many other reasons why IE below IE9 does not render a HTML5 / CSS3 layout. There are hardly any supported CSS3 features in in IE8 (even with PIE which only does some of them). If you take a look at [Browser Support Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_browsersupport.asp)
you'll see what is an is not support by the browser, without a polyfill to assist..

luckily developers have made lots of other feature available in HTML5 through the use of  [Helpful Polyfills](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills), so check out the list to see if you need some of these.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! I added a message for the viewers that they use a old browser. I will Meanwhile search for the styles that are not supported.

Comment: Applying the HTML5 Shim worked for me! The layout looks almost perfectly. I still have a DIV that should be in the middle but floats to the right. it has the posistion atribute on hidden and the overflow on: visible. But this is a small isseu that i hopefully can fix myself. Thanks!!

Comment: Glad it helped you out